# What is the "backend" in reference to the Python cryptography module?

Tags: cryptography, rsa, python

What does the ["backend"](https://cryptography.io/en/3.2.1/hazmat/backends/interfaces.html#backend-interfaces) refer to when using the Python `cryptography` module.

**For example**: The `.RSABackend` simple states: `A backend with methods for using RSA.`.

- What exactly does this mean?
- What constitutes this "backend"?

Comment: I'm not sure that this is about cryptography but about Python.

Comment: Not really a security question, i.e. off-topic. But the backend for the cryptography module is essentially the underlying library where the crypto functions are implemented, i.e. OpenSSL, The cryptography module itself just provides a common interface independent from the API of the specific library.

Comment: The one thing missing from the answer below: you don't have to worry about the backend unless you are doing something special/unique. The default backed is just fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The library in question does not implement crypto code themselves. This is because cryptographic code is prone to a wide range of problems that [most programmers don't even think about](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/209652/why-is-it-wrong-to-implement-myself-a-known-published-widely-believed-to-be/209657#209657) - or don't need to think about in their day-to-day work.

What these libraries do instead is use some other piece of software which implements them in a (hopefully) secure way. These pieces of software are referred to as backend.

#### But what specifically *is* a backend?

Class-wise, I'll take `HashBackend` as an example, but it can easily be extrapolated to other backends. It is for all intents and purposes an abstract class, that has to implement two methods:

- `hash_supported(algorithm)`
- `create_hash_ctx(algorithm)`

`hash_supported` will take an algorithm and return whether or not a specific algorithm is supported. Not every backend might support every algorithm, so you might use this to determine which algorithm you'd like to use, based on availability.

`create_hash_ctx` will take an algorithm and return a "hash context", which is the object that is used to actually calculate a hash of data.

For both of these, the class in question doesn't actually implement any of the functions. It merely defines that they exist, and the documentation explains what they *should* do. "Actual" backend code, such as the [OpenSSL backend](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/backends/openssl.html), will then interface with the actual implementation of the cryptographic code.

```
+-----------------+
|    Your Code    | This is your code, calling someting like GetHash(input.password)
+-----------------+
   |
+--v--------------+
|   High-Level    | This is the "nice" interface provided by your crypto library
|   Crypto Code   | This is what you should use 100% of the time
+-----------------+
   |
+--v--------------+
|  Hash Backend   | This is the backend that the "nice" interface calls
+-----------------+
   |
+--v--------------+
| OpenSSL Backend | This is what translates requests to a way OpenSSL understands
+-----------------+
   |
+--v--------------+
| OpenSSL Library | This is what actually does the cryptographic operations
+-----------------+
```

Depending on the cryptographic task in question, the library may call some OS function designed to fulfill some task, such as reading random data.